# (XCTestCase) How to assert if a block has been called in the main thread or outside(any other thread)?

Tags: swift, xctest

How to assert if a block has been called in the main thread or outside(any other thread)? Let suppose we have a class:

```
class A {
    func asyncOperation(handler: Void -> Void) {
        //some processing
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completionHandler)
    }
}

class ATests: XCTestCase {
    func testHandlerInMainThread(){
        let a = A()
        let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Handler must be called in main thread")

        a.asyncOperation{
            // how to get current_queue ? 
            XCTAssertEqual( current_queue, dispatch_get_main_queue())
            expectation.fulfill()
        }
        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(3, handler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `NSThread`'s class method `isMainThread` which returns `true` if the current thread is the main thread.

If you want to test whether a particular queue is actually the queue where your code executes, you might test the queue's "label":

```
 dispatch_queue_t
 dispatch_queue_create(const char *label, dispatch_queue_attr_t attr);

 const char *
 dispatch_queue_get_label(dispatch_queue_t queue);
```

The latter is more useful in Unit Tests, rather for real code. You should NOT use this approach to figure out if your code might possibly deadlock, since this is insufficient!

**Edit:**

In order to obtain the label of the current queue (in Swift):

```
let label : String? = String.fromCString(dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL))
```

Comment: How can I get reference to the current queue from block to use it with dispatch_queue_get_label? There is NSOperationQueue.currentQueue?.underlyingQueue which is not always return something..

Comment: `dispatch_queue_get_label` returns the label of the _current_ queue. So, you don't need a reference. Simply compare the expected label with the actual label when executing the block.

Comment: It's not. Parameter queue cannot be NULL.

Comment: @Danil  Ohps, my fault: you need to use a special parameter `DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL`:  `dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `dispatchPrecondition(condition:)`.

```
dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(self.myQueue))
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1780605-dispatchprecondition